# Editing input field in a Polymer Dart templatizer instance throws an error

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

We have a polymer element written in dart (version 1.0.0-rc.18).
The `<list-outer>` element uses the Templatizer behavior to iterate an object list.

```
<list-outer>
    <template>               
        <iron-label>{{row.name}}</iron-label>
        <paper-input value="{{row.name}}"></paper-input>
    </template>
</list-outer>
```

The dart part:

```
@PolymerRegister('list-outer')
class ListOuter extends PolymerElement with Templatizer {

  @property
  List<Object> datax = [
    {"name": "xxx", "age": 2},
    {"name": "yyy", "age": 3}
  ];

  ListOuter.created() : super.created() ;

  @override
  void ready() {   
    Element template = Polymer.dom(this).querySelector('template');

    this.templatize(template);

    datax.forEach((row) {
      TemplateInstance instance = this.stamp({});

      Polymer.dom(this).append(instance.root);

      instance.set('row', row);
    });
  }
}
```

If I try to edit the data in the inner `<paper-input>` we always get the  exception below. Maybe we are missing something, but don't know what.

```
**Uncaught TypeError: dataHost._templatized._notifyPath is not a function**
Polymer.Templatizer._notifyPathUpImpl @ index.html
_ijt=afoakvu673o0o9qkl500u98qfp:11533Polymer.Base._addFeature._notifyPath @ index.html
_ijt=afoakvu673o0o9qkl500u98qfp:8009Polymer.Base._addFeature.set @ index.html
_ijt=afoakvu673o0o9qkl500u98qfp:8108(anonymous function) @ index.html
_ijt=afoakvu673o0o9qkl500u98qfp:7118Polymer.Base._addFeature._notifyListener @ index.html
_ijt=afoakvu673o0o9qkl500u98qfp:7885(anonymous function) @ index.html
_ijt=afoakvu673o0o9qkl500u98qfp:7151Polymer.Base._addFeature.fire @ index.html
_ijt=afoakvu673o0o9qkl500u98qfp:6627Polymer.Bind._modelApi._notifyChange @ index.html
_ijt=afoakvu673o0o9qkl500u98qfp:6904Polymer.Base.extend._notifyEffect @ index.html
_ijt=afoakvu673o0o9qkl500u98qfp:7185Polymer.Bind._modelApi._effectEffects @ index.html
_ijt=afoakvu673o0o9qkl500u98qfp:6962Polymer.Bind._modelApi._propertySetter @ index.html
_ijt=afoakvu673o0o9qkl500u98qfp:6937setter @ index.html
```

...

Comment: Tried the same in my environment. It runs ok through the loop with no exception. On the other hand no output is produced in the dom. Googled on how this should work, but with very sparse result. Do you have suggestions where to find more info?

Comment: Now I got the valid output and reproduced the exception in Dartium. Tried to wrap the array data with `JsProxy` like this `class PersonData extends JsProxy` still same error. Building with `dart2js` and the things works ok in Chrome with no exception. Seems like something missing in the dart wrapper for running in Dartium. Tried with a `String` instead of a structured type and worked ok in Dartium.

Comment: Digged more, with `dart2js` build an exception is thrown, but swallown by Chrome and updates the value in the browser ok. The exception in Chrome is similar to that in Dartium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems as a variant of a known bug in js Polymer.

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3899

For the research, see comments.